# Insert into associative table not allowed without "optional: true"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project for one of my classes, and my current assignment requires me to allow users to enroll in courses. I have three models, User, Course, and the associative join table that belongs to both, Enrollment. The current set up in each model's rb file are as follows:

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :users, through: :enrollments
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments
end
```

The main issue is that whenever I try to add a new entry into the Enrollment model from the rails console, it gives me an error stating:

```
[4] pry(main)> enrollment = Enrollment.new(u_id: 1, c_id: 1)
=> #<Enrollment:0x00007f94bc771020 id: nil, u_id: 1, c_id: 1, ...>
[5] pry(main)> enrollment.save
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
[6] pry(main)> enrollment.errors

=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f94bc7c7290
@base=#<Enrollment:0x00007f94bc771020 id: nil, u_id: 1, c_id: 1, created_at:
nil, updated_at: nil>,
@details={:user=>[{:error=>:blank}], :course=>[{:error=>:blank}]},
@messages={:user=>["must exist"], :course=>["must exist"]}>
```

It claims that user and course must exist, but both models are populated and working individually. However, by changing my enrollment.rb to:

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :course, optional: true
end
```

it allows me to add a new Enrollment entry just fine. Would anyone know why I need "optional: true" for this to work? Does anyone know a way to fix this without using "optional: true"? Any help would be appreciated. I'm also willing to elaborate more, so please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign keys you have used are different from what you've defined in the associations and what's expected when you're using rails conventions.

According to rails conventions, `table_name_id` should be defined as a column.
so in your case it should be `course_id` and `user_id` as you're making associations with `course` model and `user` model.

It is expecting `course_id` and `user_id` as a foreign key but you've defined foreign keys as `c_id` and `u_id`.

To solve this problem you have to override rails conventions by telling it explicitly to use these foreign keys instead of what it's assuming.

Make some changes in your enrollments model

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'u_id'
  belongs_to :course, class_name: 'Course', foreign_key: 'c_id'
end
```

Now you can remove optional true.

Comment: Or rename columns to `user_id` and `course_id` in migration. It's not a good idea to use abbreviated column names, you can end up with many a_id, b_id, c_id, it's very inconvenient.

Comment: @Vasilisa indeed!

Comment: Thank you so much Gagan! This makes a lot of sense now. I made the changes and it's working now. Best to you!